# How to draw lines round selected objects and lights?

Tags: opengl

I need two things to draw in Modern OpenGL.

Please see the image: [image: Selected spotlight in blender]

1. Draw lines to represent light's position and direction
2. Draw xyz axises at the origin of a selected objects

How do I draw these? should I use fragment shader or what?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to [implement selection and transformation gizmos](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/79972/39518) — does previous Q&A on that topic give you some leads you can build on?

Comment: @DMGregory yes, that answers my second question, thank you!